# Lexmark C530dn work around for "88 Replace color cartridge" message?

Tags: colors, laser-printer, lexmark-printer

Any one come across this situation.  I've got a Lexmark C530dn printer, its color cartridges are empty but I'm only printing in black anyway.  In the past it would just complain about the color cartridges when I first turn it on but then it would allow me to print.

Now I'm just getting "88 Replace cyan cartridge".  It won't let me dismiss this message and move on and won't print even just using black either.

Does anyone know how I can tell the printer "Listen I don't really care right now just print my black and white stuff for now." ?

Just taking the cartridge out and fiddling around with it and putting it back in doesn't seem to help.  Otherwise I need to fork out for a bunch of cartridges just so that I can carry on printing even just with black.  Very disappointing design.

Answer (score 1):

I found this web-pdf online and please take a look (Search for 88) at the little troubleshooting steps.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/23345584/C530-C532-C534-Menus-Messages-Guide

At the bottom, it says to press the down arrow until the check mark (Continue) appears and then, press the check mark button to clear the message and continue printing.

I hope that this could fix the problem!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the effort, however the instructions are to replace the cartridge first.  There is no continue option at the moment, I guess there would if I actually did replace the cartridge.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this manual, p29 onwards. I know it's a C52X rather than a C53X but should work all the same. http://www.manualshark.org/manualshark/files/27/pdf_25005.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to enable "Black & White" only mode.

Unfortunately, it unnecessarily requires you to remove all the color supplies from the printer. A strange product design decision by Lexmark.

1. Turn off your printer.
2. While holding the `OK` and `Right Arrow` buttons, power on the printer.
3. Keep holding until you see that it has entered the `Configuration Menu`.
4. From there, select `Black Only Mode` option and set it to `On`.
5. Select the `Exit Config Menu` option and wait for it to reset.
6. Open the printer door and remove all six color supplies: the three color toner cartridges and the three corresponding photo-conductors. (Follow on-screen instructions if needed.)
7. Power off and on and you should be good to go. No more complaints about low CYM toner.

Remember to set your programs to print in B&W.

http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=HO2637&locale=EN&userlocale=EN